# sharing wp-include - wp-admin on same installation

Tags: wp-admin, content, include

This is not a security or privacy issue..

I have multiple wp installations  (usually a couple for project),
so in the next installation I'll be setting up I'm thinking of cutting down some space linking my new content with the wp-includes and wp-admin folders I already have on the server,

The first solution that comes to my mind is to create a normal structure (independent db - content - core)leaving wp-includes and wp-admin folders empty and creating something like a symlink (or maybe using a server htaccess redirect),

I know wp-admin can be defined in the config file but I can't find something similar for wp-includes...

What are the pros & cons of such practice,
are there any shortcuts you can suggest?

Comment: Why not multisite? What you are describing sounds to me like you are partially reimplementing a multisite setup.

Comment: I don't have much experience with multisite, but from what I know you can't have multiple DBs; I want something flexible an I don't think that having a single DB would the right solution

Comment: WordPress, configured as a multisite install, will run multiple distinct sites using the same shared core code-- more or less what you are trying to hack together. Your efforts would be better directed at understanding multisite, in my opinion.

Comment: Using MU you have 1 db, but each site has it's own tables, so it's just like having different databases. If you **absolutely** need to have different dabases you can using [HyperDb](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/). IMHO, makes no sense to have more WP installations that share folders on same server instead of using multisite.

Comment: I've read a little bit on the subject (MU) an this looks like the solution, the only thing  I'm concerned about is the plugin folder , as I believe it is shared